# How to serialise a spark sql row when it contains a comma

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am using Spark Jobserver https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver and Apache Spark for some analytic processing.

I am receiving back the following structure from jobserver when a job finishes

```
"status": "OK",
"result": [
    "[17799.91015625,null,hello there how areyou?]",
    "[50000.0,null,Hi, im fine]",
    "[0.0,null,All good]"
]
```

The result doesnt contain valid json, as explained here:

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/176

So I'm trying to convert the returned structure into a json structure, however I cant simply make the result string insert `'` (single quotes) based on the comma delimiter, as sometimes the result contains a comma itself.

How can i convert a spark Sql row into a json object in the above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a better way in the end,

from 1.3.0 onwards you can use .toJSON on a Dataframe to convert it to json

df.toJSON.collect()

to output a dataframes schema to json you can use

df.schema.json